Frobenius-Schur indicator and total orbital angular momentum
It is a well-known formula in the theory of anyons that $R_c^{ba}R_c^{ab}=\frac{\theta _c}{\theta _a\theta _b}$, where $R$ represents the braiding matrix and the $\theta$ are twists, i.e. the phase picked up under a $2\pi$ rotation. My understanding is that this comes from the following observation: a full rotation of $a$ and $b$ around each other is topologically equivalent to fusing them together, rotating the composite particle $c$, and then compensating for the rotations of $a$ and $b$.
However, let's apply the same reasoning to $R_1^{aa}$, where $a$ is a self-dual particle. In Kitaev's 2007 paper entitled Anyons in an exactly solved model and beyond, he writes the following with regard to this. 
As you can see, the correct formula is not $R_1^{aa}=\frac{1}{\theta _a}$; we also have a factor of the Frobenius-Schur indicator, supposedly representing the total angular momentum. My question is, if we are considering two particles that are in a state that can fuse into the vacuum, how can they possess odd and, hence, nonzero angular momentum? Presumably, the vacuum has no angular momentum. By conservation of momentum, we would expect that the total angular momentum before fusion is also $0$.
